# Rails4 - Maintain Context in Deeply Nested Hierarchy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a 5 to 10 level deep model hierarchy in my Rails Project.
Example (this is not the actual hierarchy)

```
(has_many)
-- Project
  -- SubProject
    -- Blog
      -- Post
        -- Comment
          -- Rating
```

Each Project has many Sub Projects, which has many Blogs, which has many Posts, and so forth.

So, in practice I want to be able to (for example) see all Posts of a specific Blog, see all Ratings of a specific Comment, and so forth. But I never want to loose the context of a earlier hierarchy level (e.g. Project).

Basically, the solution seems to be

```
resource :projects do
  resource :sub_projects do
    resource :blogs do
      resource posts do
        resource :comments do
          resource :ratings do
            # might go even deeper...
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So I can navingate to e.g. projects/2/sub_projects/3/blogs/1/posts/5/comments/2/ratings

Is there a better solution?
Besides the ugly route path I think it will be painful to work with paths like

```
new_project_sub_project_blog_post_comment_rating_path(@project, @sub_project, @blog, @post, @comment, @rating)
```

Comment: I think such a hierarchy logic in itself is a pain to work with, not only with the routes. I'd question why you need such a complex hierarchy, and make it simpler where possible. I can't give any suggestions as you're not sharing the actual hierarchy.

Comment: the best practice goes not do nest more than 2 levels deep